# Generators of alternating group $A_n$ for odd and even $n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, finitely-generated

Assume $n\geq3$ and let $A_n$ be the alternating group of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$. I would like to demonstrate the following claims:

1. $A_n=\langle(123),(12...n)\rangle$, if $n$ is odd;
2. $A_n=\langle(123),(23...n)\rangle$, if $n$ is even.

How can I use $A_n=\langle(123),(124),\ldots(12n)\rangle$ to prove these two claims? Can someone please help me get this started?

Let $n$ be odd. My idea was to show that 
$$\{(123),(124),\ldots(12n)\}\subset\langle(123),(12...n)\rangle.$$
I am not sure how to show that
$$(12k)\in\langle(123),(12...n)\rangle$$
for $4\leq k\leq n$.

Comment: Welcome to Stackexchange. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score 1):

By repeatedly conjugating $(123)$ by $(123\ldots n)$, you obtain the transpositions $(123)$, $(234)$, $(345),\ldots,(n-2,n-1,n)$, $(n-1, n,1)$, and $(n,1,2)$ (and their inverses); in case you are unfamiliar, conjugation $x$ by $y$ for me means computing $yxy^{-1}$.

Once you have these, from $(123)$ you can get $(124)$ by taking, e.g., $(345)(123)(345)^{-1}$. Then $(125)$ by conjugating again; etc. You can easily obtain all $3$-cycles of the form $(12a)$, $3\leq a\leq n$.

Similarly for 2.